# Allow Requests to App_Data

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, web-config

I want to allow users to request files located in App_Data Folder. This is the error:

> Error Summary
>
> HTTP Error 404.8 - Not Found
>
> The request filtering module is configured to deny a path in the URL that contains a hiddenSegment section.

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Its not possible to access `App_Data` folder directly as it is used as data-storage for web application, for security reasons of the stored data you can access database from it only using connectionstring.

web.config

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="AddressBookConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\myDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

check this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31557/A-Beginner-s-Guide-to-ASP-NET-Application-Folders#h

**UPDATE**
Programatically we can access any file in web application and write it to response:

```
public class FileAccessHandler:IHttpHandler
{
    public FileAccessHandler()
    {
        //
        // TODO: Add constructor logic here
        //
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        String FileName = Path.GetFileName(context.Request.PhysicalPath);
        String AssetName = HttpContext.Current.Request.MapPath(Path.Combine(HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath, "App_Data/" + FileName));

        if (File.Exists(AssetName))
        {
            context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
            context.Response.BinaryWrite(File.ReadAllBytes(AssetName));
            context.Response.End();
        }
    }
}
```

[Download: App_Data access sample](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0ByNSdMMJ6S0GamJ4NDdtdWlmMEE)

Comment: This answer is only half-true: You can make the request filtering module allow that path.

Comment: Even though this post was done long ago, this is the one that helped me! After many hours of struggling, thinking its either the Hosting company restricting access or having to add trust levels or trying to make changes because the RadAjaxPanel was causing issues...It all came down to not being able to access the App_Data folder! Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

This is not recommended as app data is meant for application files but this can be done by adding the following line to the config

```
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <hiddenSegments>
          <remove segment="app_data" />
        </hiddenSegments>
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
```